# How to open Windows Certificate Viewer (not Manager)

Tags: c#, .net, windows, x509

When you open a .crt file in explorer, a Windows Certificate viewer shows the details of the cert.

I need to open this viewer from .net (c#).
I've found out that the file system32\cryptext.dll opens the viewer:
rundll32.exe cryptext.dll,CryptExtOpenCER

Is there a .net code / class to open this window (or a similar one) directly, if not how do I call the .dll function without rundll32?

Note: I do NOT mean the certmgr.msc itself.

Answer (score 0):

You can call

```
Process.Start("c:\\certificate.crt");
```

given the .crt file type is correctly associated in windows explorer

Comment: That's not much better than calling rundll32.
And the files don't always have the correct extension.

Comment: @manuel Alternativley, use the X509CertificateClass and build your own dialog showing the information you´re looking for http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509certificate(v=VS.100).aspx